# How to solve compilation error when building Dlib code.?

Tags: c++, image-processing, mingw

I was tried to run sample Dlib code Using MinGW and Netbeans. But I got compilation error.

Steps Followed:

1.Downloaded Dlib package from Dlib website.

2.Include root folder(Dlib) in c++ Compiler setting and also set -std=c++11 in compiler additional flag.

3.Copy the sample from example of Dlib folder.

4.Compiled.

I got Bellow error when compiling code.Give me simple steps for executing Dlib sample code(for example face_detection_ex code in example in Dlib)

```
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `Z12loadIbugDataN5boost10filesystem4pathE':
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:124: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::extension() const'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:133: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::replace_extension(boost::filesystem::path const&)'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:355: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:355: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:355: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:358: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::add_options()'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:358: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, char const*)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:360: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:362: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:365: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description_easy_init::operator()(char const*, boost::program_options::value_semantic const*, char const*)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:366: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:367: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, bool)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:370: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
D:\NetBeansProjects\SDM/main.cpp:373: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::notify(boost::program_options::variables_map&)'
```

Comment: Those are not, technically, compiler errors, those are *linker* errors. You need to *link* with the appropriate Boost libraries.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for your reply. But boost is header only package..So no need to link Library.How to link lib for boost..?

Comment: Some Boost libraries are header only, but not all. For example, the Boost Filesystem and Boost Program Options libraries are *not* header-only libraries.

Comment: Thanks.I created library file using mingw and linked with it. I got bellow error  " undefined reference to `vl_hog_new(VlHogVariant_, unsigned long long, int)'" is anything needed lib file for this one..?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Linux You need to add libvl.so to your Linker setting.
In a 64-bit system you may find this file in /vlfeat/bin/glnxa64/.